# How to fix allocated memory from a struct hack in a different method?

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-allocation

I'm developing a driver in C for communication and the messages exchanged don't have a fixed size. The recommendation of communication bus is to use structs for multi-topics, which is also my case.

My 1st problem: I have to keep listening for new messages, and when I get one I have to process message data (it has a delay) and still listening for new messages.

1st solution: using thread when got new messages to process data.

My 2nd problem: Data in message can have multiple data of a struct, and  my communicator requires using a struct to organize this multiple values.

2nd solution: using struct hack to allocate memory dynamic size of struct.

My current problem: when I'd pass my struct as argument to the thread, or any function, I'm loosing data structure and getting wrong values.

A short test which a made is:

```
typedef struct test{
    int size;
    int value[];
} test;

void allocation(test *v){
    test *aux = (test *)malloc(sizeof(test)+3*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    aux->value[0] = 2;
    aux->size = 3;
    aux->value[1] = 1;
    aux->value[2] = 5;
    printf("Teste1 %d\n",aux->size);
    for(i=0; i < aux->size; i++){
        printf("%d\n", aux->value[i]);
    }
    *v = *aux;
}

void cleanup(test *v){
    free(v);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    test v;
    int i;

    allocation(&v);
    printf("Teste2 %d\n",v.size);
    for(i=0; i < v.size; i++){
        printf("%d\n", v.value[i]);
    }
    //cleanup(&v);
    return 0;
}
```

In this test I got right values in first print and wrong values in second (only `v.size` is giving a right value).

And my struct is a little more complex than that in test. My struct is like:

```
typedef struct test1{
    double v1;
    double v2;
} test1;

typedef struct test2{
    int size;
    test1 values[];
} test2;
```

Do you know how to fix my memory struct in that function, once I have all elements necessary to fix? Please, keep in mind that is desirable (not required) that I could also allocate multiple `test2` data.

Comment: Note that using `[]` at the end of a structure is a _flexible array member_ (FAM) and is fully supported in C99 and later.  The 'struct hack' uses `[1]` instead of `[]` and is not fully supported (though it usually works, not least because it was necessary before FAMs were introduced, and is still needed to retain backwards compatibility for working code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `v` as non-pointer, meaning that the memory is already allocated for `v` when you declare it in `main`. Sending the reference to your `allocation` only copies the `size` correctly since it is not dynamically allocated. Correct way to do this would be to:

- Declare your `v` as pointer
- Make your `allocation` return `test*` (`test* allocation()`)
- Assign it to `v` in `main`. i.e. something like `v = allocate()`
- And use `v` like a pointer from then on

EDIT: Since OP wants this to work only as arguments, best way to go about it is using double pointer. Check the following code:

```
typedef struct test{
    int size;
    int value[];
} test;

void allocation(test **v){
    test *aux = (test *)malloc(sizeof(test)+3*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    aux->value[0] = 2;
    aux->size = 3;
    aux->value[1] = 1;
    aux->value[2] = 5;
    printf("Teste1 %d\n",aux->size);
    for(i=0; i < aux->size; i++){
        printf("%d\n", aux->value[i]);
    }
    *v = aux;
}

void cleanup(test *v){
    free(v);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    test **v;
    v = malloc (sizeof (test*));
    int i;

    allocation(v);
    printf("Teste2 %d\n",(*v)->size);
    for(i=0; i < (*v)->size; i++){
        printf("%d\n", (*v)->value[i]);
    }
    //cleanup(&v);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that your cleanup will change too after this.

Comment: Your answer really can fix the test, but I can't use that in thread, once the creation of a thread we pass function and struct address as arguments, I still have to solve this problem using arguments. Do you know another solution?

Comment: Yeah you can use double pointers, check out the working code in my edited answer. You'll have to tweak it a bit according to your setup ofc.

Answer (score 2):

The thing here is that you assign structs with incomplete member `int value[]`; Though it is in principle OK to copy two structs by value (and this is actually what happens if you write `*v = *aux`); However, as the compiler does not know which size member `value[]` will take on at runtime, the "sizeof" of `v` as well as the size of `*aux` is always 4, i.e. the known size of the one int member `size`. Hence, only this is copied, whereas the `value[]`-array simply gets not copied.

A way out out this situation would be require a pointer to a pointer (i.e. `allocation(test **v)`, such that the memory reserved can be directly assigned to it, using a pointer to struct test in main, i.e. `test *vptr`, and call `allocation(&vptr)`.

If you cannot avoid passing a reverence to the value (instead of a reference to a pointer to the value), I suppose you'll have to use `memcpy` to transfer the contents. But this does actually not make sense, because then the receiver must provide enough space to take on the `value[]`-array in advance (which is not the case if you simple declare a variable of the form `test v`). An then the `malloc` and the `aux` would make no sense; you could directly write into object `v` passed by reference.